# Javascript strings : Appending django urls

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to create a simple url builder. For example in javascript I have:

```
var url = document.URL;
```

If I wanted to append something to the url I could just simply type its pattern, but in Django we can use something like this:

```
url = url + "{% url 'object_view' %}";
alert(url);
```

The problem is where the document.URL and Django URL creates a pattern like this:

```
http://localhost:8000//objects/view/
```

I've tried looking at Javascript string manipulation such as `trim()` and `replace()`, but both doesn't have the manipulation to just drop the single slash in the string from `document.URL`.

If I replace all () it may get affected if for example my `document.URL` is something like: `http://localhost:8000/something/something2/`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the output of `console.log( document.URL, url );` before `alert`.

Comment: `replace('//', '/') ?`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can replace `//` if not preceded by `:`

```
"http://localhost:8000//objects/view/".replace( /(?<!:)\/\//g,  "/" )
```

Comment: I've tried the same thing that Lwin Htoo Ko suggested. `replace('//', '/')` before I posted this question. It doesn't work as well. Nor `url = document.URL; url = url.trim()` before I append it to `url = url + "{% url 'routes_view' %}".toString();`

Comment: yes but for some reason it messes with my leaflet map (doesn't show anymore) and also doesn't alert on button click. Anyways I just found a solution :)

Comment: this: `url = url.slice(0, -1);` then append it to the django url

Comment: But did you tried what I had recommended? Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Yes I did. But again, it doesn't even get to alert also it messes up my leaflet map ( it doesn't show anymore)  `switch(page){
            case 0:{

                url = url + "{% url 'routes_view' %}".toString();
                url = url.replace( /(?<!:)\/\//g,  "/" );
                alert(url);
                //window.location.href(url);
            }
                break;`

Answer (score 0):

Figured that I should be able to drop the last `/` from `document.URL` by using `slice()`

```
var url = document.URL;
    url = url.slice(0, -1);
    alert(url);
```

Output:

```
http://localhost:8000
```

then append the remaining:

```
url = url + "{% url 'routes_view' %}".toString();
```

Output:

```
http://localhost:8000/something/something2/
```